# How to make radio reception better with antenna 133 cm long

Tags: rf, antenna, radio

My low cost FM radio receiver [Philips MCM129](http://www.philips.pl/c-p/MCM129_12/-) is not receiveing some radio stations well. It has antenna made of about 133 cm long thin insulated wire which I suspect is the rason of the problem.

Can I make the reception better by making the wire longer/shorter?

Comment: What happens if you move the receiver away from walls? (Assuming it is near a wall).

Comment: How do you know it isn't the limit of operation for the radio?

Comment: If it has a coax connector for an external antenna, you can mount a better antenna in the attic for 10-20dB moe signal strength.

Comment: Does it have an FM mono button - if it does, press it

Answer (score 1):

For FM radio reception getting the antenna higher off the ground is one of the best options.  Unlike AM radio FM signals are more line of sight dependent.  So if you are in an area that is generally low, such as a valley, or surrounded by hills, your reception may be poor for some or all stations.

Ideally try buying a simple low cost FM antenna, see amazon for starters:
[http://www.amazon.com/Stellar-Labs-30-2435-Outdoor-Omnidirectional/dp/B00DHHOZBI/ref=sr_1_5/175-5135060-7871912?s=aht&ie=UTF8&qid=1446522891&sr=1-5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DHHOZBI)

Here are a few links to help make your own wire antenna:

http://siber-sonic.com/FM_reception/rooftop.html

http://www.robertsewell.ca/yahoo/fmaerial.html

Comment: I'll definitely try external antenna (unless my radio does not have socket for external one) but will this overcome what Mark Ch pointed - "Therefore, even at the ideal length, these antennas still have a very poor response"

Answer (score 0):

the simple wire antenna is a basic monopole, and so the ideal length for the FM radio frequencies is a quarter wavelength, approximately 3e8 / 100MHz / 4 = 0.75m.

but in the reality the ground plane for the monopole is provided only by the PCB and casing of the radio and is extremely poor. Therefore, even at the ideal length, these antennas still have a very poor response.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with FM.

Comment: @Andy aka yes you're right, but specifically FM radio 88-108 MHz.

Comment: @MarkCh When receiving the length of the antenna is irrelevant. The antenna has an effective area that depends on the frequency of the signal being received and not the length.

Comment: @vini_i I think you need to do some research here dude!!

Comment: @vini_i are you thinking about a parabolic reflector?

Comment: @Andyaka The effective area or aperture of the antenna is the wave length squared divided by 4pi. Your welcome to have a read. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_aperture

Comment: @vini_i this is only true for a lossless isotropic antenna, not a real antenna

Comment: @MarkCh The calculation of power received depends on, the effective area of the transmitter, effective area of the receiver, the directivity of both, the power transmitted, distance and wave length. These are all properties of real antennas. This is all summed up in Friis transmission equations.

Comment: @vini_i a lossless isotropic antenna is a theoretical point source, with a size of zero and therefore has no frequency response. A real antenna has physical dimensions which introduce a frequency response. The friis equations are only valid within the passband of the antenna, not outside, which for a monopole, means at the resonant frequency of the antenna (based on its length). If you do not believe this, build one and measure it.

Comment: @MarkCh I couldn't have put it better.

Comment: @MarkCh That resonant frequency comes from other properties like inductance rather than antenna properties. That resonance can be setup using other components such as a super regenerative receiver.

Comment: @vini_i inductance of a wire is a function of its length.

Comment: @vini_i a real dipole antenna has distributed inductance and capacitance - it is basically an opened-out quarter wave transmission line. This produces maximum voltage at the ends of the dipole's wires. This maximizes E and H fields produced by a transmitting antenna. You can make an antenna shorter by using a based loading inductor but we're not talking about this.

Comment: @vini_i maybe raise this as a question yourself and let the great and good in to respond.

Comment: there is a good free utility based on NEC4 called 4NEC2 (http://www.qsl.net/4nec2/), which can give frequency responses and radiation patterns for custom antenna designs. It is well worth a play.